# How can I find out how many cookies Opera has?

Tags: delphi, cookies, opera, file-format

Does anyone know where I can get the file format for the Opera 10+ cookies4.dat file? I'm trying to just get the count of total cookies, something like this:

```
function CookieCount(const theFilename: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := OperaCookieCount(theFilename);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading up on the fileformat. I could not find any current links on Opera.com, but this link is helpful : http://www.peeep.us/4899d1fa

Also O4FE seems to be able to parse cookies4.dat, so you might also want to look into it at http://users.westelcom.com/jsegur/#ofe

Comment: Yup, file format doc was taken off-line. I believe this is a sign of upcoming format changes (wand.dat format has been silently changed already). Yet, actual version still writes compliant files.